# How to redirect from tag page to post page WP?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, post, tags

when I'm looking in Google for my site with keywords i find them with tags like that ex: `http://example.com/tag/post/` and I need them to redirect from Google to a post like that `http://example.com/post/`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say a `tag` is being added to each URL, you need to modify your [permalink structure](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Choosing_your_permalink_structure) to point to `/%postname%/` instead of whatever structure is there now.

Please see the [Codex on using permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for more information.

Comment: When I just surfing page all links are good, but Google find posts by them tags `http://example.com/tag/post/` it's also fine, but when I press the link Google redirects to `http://example.com/tag/post/` and problem is that this page is different from original post so i need that link to redirect just to `http://example.com/post/`. Simply saying just remove /tag/ from URL when i press the link. I think I have to change something with .htaccess but I don't know what :( I tried to change permalink structure inside WP.

Comment: What happens if you manually visit `http://example.com/post/` directly, rather than `http://example.com/tag/post/`?

Comment: Now there is other issue I think. Dunno why I didn't tried to go manually. So my posts are categorized with tags but they don't have personal separate page, you can just surf them. So when you go manually its not found page. Now I think the best way to do this is just redirect from Google to that category page where that post is.